# Replace all NAs with -1 in r with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, r-mice

I'm currently working with the tidyverse in R. After using mice to impute NAs some of the columns still have NAs due to the fact that they are poorly populated to begin with (I believe). As a final check I want to replace all of the remaining NAs with -1. It usually just happens in a single column depending on the dataset. Long story short I'm doing the same process on multiple locations and sometimes Col1 is populated wonderfully in region A, but badly in region B.

Currently I'm doing the following.

```
    Clean.df <- df %>% mutate(
              coalesce(Col1 ,-1),
              coalesce(Col2, -1),
              ....)
```

And I'm doing that for 31 columns which makes me think there must be an easier way. I attempted read the coalesce documentation and tried to replace it with the name of the data frame, no luck.

Thanks for the insight.

Comment: You've asked specifically for a `dplyr` answer. This can sometimes be limiting. A "base R" solution is often concise and perfectly understandable, as: `df[is.na(df)] <- -1`

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't provide any data, I am using a sample data frame to show how every `NA` in a data frame can be replaced with a given value (`-1`):

```r
library(tidyverse)

# creating example dataset
example_df <- ggplot2::msleep

# looking at NAs
example_df
#> # A tibble: 83 x 11
#>    name  genus vore  order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Chee~ Acin~ carni Carn~ lc                  12.1      NA        NA    
#>  2 Owl ~ Aotus omni  Prim~ <NA>                17         1.8      NA    
#>  3 Moun~ Aplo~ herbi Rode~ nt                  14.4       2.4      NA    
#>  4 Grea~ Blar~ omni  Sori~ lc                  14.9       2.3       0.133
#>  5 Cow   Bos   herbi Arti~ domesticated         4         0.7       0.667
#>  6 Thre~ Brad~ herbi Pilo~ <NA>                14.4       2.2       0.767
#>  7 Nort~ Call~ carni Carn~ vu                   8.7       1.4       0.383
#>  8 Vesp~ Calo~ <NA>  Rode~ <NA>                 7        NA        NA    
#>  9 Dog   Canis carni Carn~ domesticated        10.1       2.9       0.333
#> 10 Roe ~ Capr~ herbi Arti~ lc                   3        NA        NA    
#> # ... with 73 more rows, and 3 more variables: awake <dbl>, brainwt <dbl>,
#> #   bodywt <dbl>

# replacing NAs with -1
purrr::map_dfr(.x = example_df,
           .f = ~ tidyr::replace_na(data = ., -1))
#> # A tibble: 83 x 11
#>    name  genus vore  order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Chee~ Acin~ carni Carn~ lc                  12.1      -1        -1    
#>  2 Owl ~ Aotus omni  Prim~ -1                  17         1.8      -1    
#>  3 Moun~ Aplo~ herbi Rode~ nt                  14.4       2.4      -1    
#>  4 Grea~ Blar~ omni  Sori~ lc                  14.9       2.3       0.133
#>  5 Cow   Bos   herbi Arti~ domesticated         4         0.7       0.667
#>  6 Thre~ Brad~ herbi Pilo~ -1                  14.4       2.2       0.767
#>  7 Nort~ Call~ carni Carn~ vu                   8.7       1.4       0.383
#>  8 Vesp~ Calo~ -1    Rode~ -1                   7        -1        -1    
#>  9 Dog   Canis carni Carn~ domesticated        10.1       2.9       0.333
#> 10 Roe ~ Capr~ herbi Arti~ lc                   3        -1        -1    
#> # ... with 73 more rows, and 3 more variables: awake <dbl>, brainwt <dbl>,
#> #   bodywt <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Suggestion/request (it is a personal preference, I recognize): especially in answers when askers are likely new to R, it is a little overkill to encourage `library(tidyverse)` when you only need two of the 25 dependent packages. It's not a hard-and-fast rule, but loading 25 vice 2 (well, 2 plus their silent dependencies) can be a big difference, especially if (like me) many of them are not actually installed. I really like that you specified them with double-colons, e.g., `purrr::map_dfr`: it's a python-like mechanism for keeping the namespace explicit. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Indrajeet's answer that is pure `dplyr`. Using Indrajeet's recommendation of `ggplot2::msleep`:

```
library(dplyr)
ggplot2::msleep %>%
  mutate_at(vars(sleep_rem, sleep_cycle), ~ if_else(is.na(.), -1, .))
# # A tibble: 83 x 11
#    name  genus vore  order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake
#    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 Chee~ Acin~ carni Carn~ lc                  12.1      -1        -1      11.9
#  2 Owl ~ Aotus omni  Prim~ <NA>                17         1.8      -1       7  
#  3 Moun~ Aplo~ herbi Rode~ nt                  14.4       2.4      -1       9.6
#  4 Grea~ Blar~ omni  Sori~ lc                  14.9       2.3       0.133   9.1
#  5 Cow   Bos   herbi Arti~ domesticated         4         0.7       0.667  20  
#  6 Thre~ Brad~ herbi Pilo~ <NA>                14.4       2.2       0.767   9.6
#  7 Nort~ Call~ carni Carn~ vu                   8.7       1.4       0.383  15.3
#  8 Vesp~ Calo~ <NA>  Rode~ <NA>                 7        -1        -1      17  
#  9 Dog   Canis carni Carn~ domesticated        10.1       2.9       0.333  13.9
# 10 Roe ~ Capr~ herbi Arti~ lc                   3        -1        -1      21  
# # ... with 73 more rows, and 2 more variables: brainwt <dbl>, bodywt <dbl>
```

If you want the nuclear option over all columns (`numeric` and `character`), then use:

```
ggplot2::msleep %>%
  mutate_all(~ ifelse(is.na(.), -1, .))
# # A tibble: 83 x 11
#    name  genus vore  order conservation sleep_total sleep_rem sleep_cycle awake
#    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>              <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 Chee~ Acin~ carni Carn~ lc                  12.1      -1        -1      11.9
#  2 Owl ~ Aotus omni  Prim~ -1                  17         1.8      -1       7  
#  3 Moun~ Aplo~ herbi Rode~ nt                  14.4       2.4      -1       9.6
#  4 Grea~ Blar~ omni  Sori~ lc                  14.9       2.3       0.133   9.1
#  5 Cow   Bos   herbi Arti~ domesticated         4         0.7       0.667  20  
#  6 Thre~ Brad~ herbi Pilo~ -1                  14.4       2.2       0.767   9.6
#  7 Nort~ Call~ carni Carn~ vu                   8.7       1.4       0.383  15.3
#  8 Vesp~ Calo~ -1    Rode~ -1                   7        -1        -1      17  
#  9 Dog   Canis carni Carn~ domesticated        10.1       2.9       0.333  13.9
# 10 Roe ~ Capr~ herbi Arti~ lc                   3        -1        -1      21  
# # ... with 73 more rows, and 2 more variables: brainwt <dbl>, bodywt <dbl>
```

Note that I'm no longer using `dplyr::if_else`, since the function needs to be versatile with (or ignorant of) the different types. Since `base::ifelse` will happily/silently(/sloppily?) convert, we're good.

Comment: There are still `NA`s remaining in columns `vore`, `conservation`, etc.

Comment: Sure there are! I was demonstrating the basic concept, assuming the OP could adapt for their own needs. Replacing with `mutate_all(~ ifelse(is.na(.), -1, .))` works fine as the nuclear option; cannot use `dplyr::if_else` without a bit more code, since columns are of varied types.